# Thinking sphinx not accessing deployment recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx

The [thinking sphinx manual](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/deployment.html) alludes to a capistrano recipe which I assume is the [following.](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/blob/master/lib/thinking_sphinx/capistrano/v3.rb)

However deployment is interrupted for motive

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class
```

and it complains about this line

```
require 'thinking_sphinx/capistrano'
```

Does this require a particular step when installing ts ?

Comment: Which version of Thinking Sphinx are you using? And where do you have that require statement? (It should be in your Capfile.)

Comment: Version 3.0.3.  I've tried placing the require statement in both capfile and deploy file.  It returns the same error in both cases

Comment: I'm not sure if TS v3.0.3 supports Capistrano v3. There's certainly been some changes in Capistrano support in TS between 3.0.3 and 3.1.2 (which was released recently).

Comment: the 'upgrading' page makes no mention of intra-v3 upgrades. Anything to be concerned about / watch for in movin' on up?

Comment: Check out the release notes - they exist for 3.0.6-3.1.2, which is pretty close to what you're dealing with. https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases

Comment: Ah.  was looking in the wrong place!  Cheers!

Comment: The docs are normally a great source - there is a link up the top of the upgrading page pointing to these newer release notes, though it is a bit misleading (under a section about upgrading Sphinx rather than Thinking Sphinx).